# LINQ with Chained Methods - Context Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am delving into LINQ and VS2012 is throwing a fit about my LINQ statement, in the OrderBy:

```
The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
```

**What I am trying to do is this:**

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts 
WHERE DateCreated >= [SOMEDATE VALUE] 
AND   DateCreated <= [SOMEDATE VALUE]
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
LIMIT 100
```

**LINQ**

```
model.Contacts = db.Contacts.Where((x =>(x.DateCreated >= p.DateFrom) && (x.DateCreated <= p.DateTo))).OrderByDescending(x.DateCreated).Take(100).ToList();
```

What I am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't defined x as a parameter in the orderby lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got too many parentheses in your lambda expression.  Also, you don't have a lambda variable in your `OrderByDescending` method call.

Try this:

```
model.Contacts = db.Contacts
    .Where(x => x.DateCreated >= p.DateFrom && x.DateCreated <= p.DateTo)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: Should be: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)`

Comment: Don't think it's the parantheses usage. They're balanced and just encapsulate each binary expression.

Comment: @bmused: I've never seen them used quite like that before, and lambda expressions of the type `() =>` (which takes no parameters) and `(a, b) =>` (which takes two) are legal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I agree. It's difficult to read. Just not convinced its the source of error here.

Comment: @bmused Parentheses is not the issue. The `OrderByDescending` clause was causing problem as it wasn't a lambda expression and `x` wasn't in the scope of the executing method.

Comment: yes, it was a paren issue Robert's suggestion fixed it. Thanks all

Comment: @SimonBelanger, I agree :) but I was almost convinced.